# Inequality of Euclidean Distances in Aligning Point Clouds

Tags: geometry, inequality, metric-spaces, least-squares

A, B, C are each a sequence of n points in ordinary 3D space.

The squared Eudlidean distance between i<sup>th</sup> point of A and the i<sup>th</sup> point of B is: $$ d(\vec{a}_i, \vec{b}_i) = (a_{ix} - b_{ix})^2 + (a_{iy} - b_{iy})^2 + (a_{iz} - b_{iz})^2 $$

The sum of squared Euclidean distance between corresponding points of A and B is:

$$ d(A, B) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} d(\vec{a}_i, \vec{b}_i) $$

Define the least sum of squared Euclidean distance A and B, $ \Delta(A, B)   $, as the least d(A, B) under all possible reordering of the sequence of points in B. [Updated after quasi gives a counter example when the points are not allowed to reorder]

A new sequence of points C<sub>A</sub> can be formed by rotating, translating, and reordering C to minimize $ \Delta(A, C) $. Similarly, we can create another sequence of points C<sub>B</sub>. (This is translating & rotating a 3D object so that it best matches another 3D object).

Is $ \Delta(C_{A}, C_{B}) \ge \Delta(A, B) $ always true for all possible A, B, and C?

Comment: I found this when I write unit tests. Can't quite prove or disprove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, it's false.

We can stay on the real line (i.e., $A,B,C$ will be sequences of real numbers).

Let $n=2$, and let
\begin{align*}
A&=-3,-1\\[4pt]
B&=3,\;1\\[4pt]
C&=0,\;0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
C_A&=-2,-2\\[4pt]
C_B&=\;\;2,\;2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
but
$$\Delta(C_{A}, C_{B}) = 32 < 40 = \Delta(A, B)$$
The above counterexample was based on the conditions originally specified.

But with the updated conditions, it's still false.

In the plane, with $n=3$, let
\begin{align*}
A&=(-2,0),\;(-12,0),\;(-12,24)\\[4pt]
B&=(+2,0),\;(+12,0),\;(+12,24)\\[4pt]
C&=(0,0),\;(0,0),\;(0,0)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
C_A&=(-7,12),\;(-7,12),(-7,12)\\[4pt]
C_B&=(+7,12),\;(+7,12),(+7,12)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
but
$$\Delta(C_{A}, C_{B}) = (3)(14^2) = 588$$ 
$$\Delta(A, B) = (2)(14^2) + 24^2 = 968$$

Comment: make sense. i was actually try to align two shapes. so that allows rearranging the points in the sequence to minimize the distance. What to do if I found a typo in my question o.o

Comment: Is $C_B$ again the centroid of the 3 points in B?

Comment: No, $C_B$ is the circumcenter of the triangle formed by the $3$ points of $B$.

Comment: to add another argument to *quasi* answer, consider A,B to be quite similar clouds much oblate vertically, and separated at some distance. Consider C instead to be quite symmetrical  , with the points concentrated near the outer surface, which has diameter much larger than A and B. Clearly the $C_A$ and $C_B$ will be centered on A and B, and since the distance is taken at the square, you can easily deduct that your hypothesis does not hold.

Comment: ty. i dumped the test i wrote.